# references in perl: hash of array to another array

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, reference

I have a problem with referencing a hash in an array to another array.
I have an array @result which looks like this:

```
@result = (

{ "type" => "variable",
  "s" => "NGDP",
  "variable" => "NGDP" },

{"type" => "subject",
  "s" => "USA",
  "subject" => "USA",
  "variable" => "NGDP" },

{ "type" => "colon",
  "s" => ",",
  "colon" => "," }, 

{ "type" => "subject",
  "s" => "JPN",
  "subject" => "JPN",
  "variable" => "NGDP" },

{ "type" => "operator",
  "s" => "+",
  "operator => "+" },

{"type" => "subject",
  "s" => "CHN",
  "subject" => "CHN",
  "variable" => "NGDP" },
);
```

I want to divide this array into colons and push elements of the @result array to another array, so i wrote the script:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $#result; $i++) {  

if (defined $result[$i]{subject} or $result[$i]{operator} and not defined $result[$i]{colon}) {
  push @part_col, \%{$result[$i]};
}

elsif ($i == $#result) {
  push @part_col_all, \@part_col;
}

elsif (defined $result[$i]{colon}) {
  push @part_col_all, \@part_col;
  my @part_col;
 }
}
```

So what I need is that if I print out `$part_col_all[0][0]{subject}` the result will be `"USA"`,

and for `$part_col_all[1][0]{subject}` will be `"JPN"`,

and for `$part_col_all[1][1]{operator}` will be `"+"` etc.

My result for `$part_col_all[0][0]{subject}` is `"USA"`

and for `$part_col_all[0][1]{subject}` is `"JPN"` which should be in `$part_col_all[1][0]{subject}`.

The result for `$part_col_all[0][3]{subject}` is `"CHN"`, while it should be in $part_col_all[1][2]{subject}.

I'm making an application which is creating graphs from economical data based on a certain economical input. The @result array is my preprocessed input where I know to which country which variable belongs. If I get an input like GDP USA CAN, JPN+CHN I need to split this input to GDP USA CAN and JPN+CHN. That's why I made a condition, if colon is found, push everything in @part_col to the first element of @part_col_all, and then if it's on the end of the input, push JPN+CHN to the second element of @push_col_all.

So @part_col_all should looks like this:

```
@part_col_all = (
    (   
        {"type" => "subject",
        "s" => "USA",
        "subject" => "USA",
        "variable" => "NGDP" },

        {"type" => "subject",
        "s" => "CAN",
        "subject" => "CAN",
        "variable" => "NGDP" },
    ),

    (
        { "type" => "subject",
        "s" => "JPN",
        "subject" => "JPN",
        "variable" => "NGDP" },

        { "type" => "operator",
        "s" => "+",
        "operator" => "+" },

        {"type" => "subject",
        "s" => "CHN",
        "subject" => "CHN",
        "variable" => "NGDP" },

    )
);
```

I dont know what I'm doing wrong. Sorry if there are any basic mistakes, im a beginner. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're missing a quote:

```
{ "type" => "operator",
  "s" => "+",
  "operator" => "+" },
           ^ missing
```

As for printing, you can do the following:

```
foreach my $part (@part_col){
    print $part->{operator}."\n";
}
```

Or do whatever you want in the print cycle with the values

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [Perl Reference Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) to help you.

There's no sin in dereferencing to simplify your code:

```
my @part_col;
my @part_col_all;

for $i ( 0..$#array ) {
    my %hash = ${ $result[$i] };  # Make it easy on yourself. Dereference
    if ( defined $hash{subject} or defined $hash{operator} and not defined $hash{colon} ) {
        push @part_col, \%hash;  # or push, @par_col, $result[$i]
    }
}
```

Notice I changed the `for` from the three part setup you had to a cleaner and easier to understand way of stating it.

Looking closer at your data structure, I notice that `$hash{type}` will tell you whether or not `$hash{operator}`, `$hash{subject}`, or `$hash{colon}` is defined. Let's just use `$hash{type}` and simplify that `if`:

```
my @part_col;
my @part_col_all;

for my $i ( 0..$#array ) { 
    my %hash = ${ $result[$i] };  # Make it easy on yourself. Dereference
    if ( $hash{type} eq "subject" or $hash{type} eq "operator" ) {
        push @part_col, \%hash;  # or push, @par_col, $result[$i]
    }
}
```

In fact, since `@array` is just an array, I'll treat it like one. I'll use a simple `for` structure to go through each element of my array. Each element is a hash_reference, so:

```
for my $hash_ref ( @array ) {
    my %hash = %{ %hash_ref };
    if ( $hash{type} eq "subject" or $hash{type} eq "operator" ) {
        push @part_col, \%hash;
    }
}
```

And further simplification, I can dereference and talk about a particular element of my hash all at once by using the `->` syntax:

```
for my $hash_ref ( @array ) {
    if ( $hash_ref->{type} eq "subject" or $hash_ref->{type} eq "operator" ) {
        push @part_col, $hash_ref;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to understand the rest of your code:

```
    elsif ($i == $#result) {
        push @part_col_all, \@part_col;
    }

    elsif (defined $hash_ref->{colon}) {
        push @part_col_all, \@part_col;
        my @part_col;
    }
}
```

These *pushes* of `@part_col` onto `@part_col_all` confuse me. Exactly what are you trying to store in `@part_col_all`? Remember that \@part_col is the location in memory where you're storing `@part_col`. You're pushing that same memory location over and over onto that hash, so you're storing the same reference over and over again. Is that really what you want? I doubt it.

You need to do is to decide exactly what your data structure really represents. A data structure should have a solid definition. What does the data structure `@part_col_all` represent? What does the data structure `$part_col_all[$i]` represent? What does the data structure `$part_col_all[$i]->[$j]` represent? Without knowing this, it's very hard to answer the rest of your question.

Are you storing elements where the type is `colon` in one array and everything else in another array? Or are you storing everything in one array, and in another array, storing everything that's not a type `colon`?

Once I understand this, I can answer the rest of your question.

## Addendum

> Thank you for your reply, I will try that way and write my results. It is realy helpful. I updated my question with more information about data structure of @part_col_all. I hope that you understand what I'm trying to explain, if not I'll try it again.

---

If I understand what you're doing, someone enters in `NGDP USA , JPN+CNA` and that means you're comparing the NGDP between the United States vs. Japan and China combined.

It seems to me that you would want three separate variables:

- `$parameter` - What you are measuring. (GDP, etc.)
- `@countries_set_1` - The first set of countries
- `@countries_set_2` - The second set of countries which you're comparing against the first set.

And, what you call the *colon* (which we would call a *comma* in the U.S.) as a separator between the first set of countries vs. the second set. Then, you'd simply go through a loop. It could be that the two arrays are merely two elements of the same array, and the *sets of countries* are array references. I imagine something like this:

```
@input = qw(GDP USA, JPN CHN); # Compare the GDP of the USA with Japan and China together
my $parameter = shift @input;  # Remove what you're measuring
my @country_sets;              # An array of arrays
my $set = 0                    # Which set you're on
for my $value ( @input ) {
    if ( $value eq "," ) {
       $set += 1;              # Next Set
       next;
    }
    push @{ $country_sets[$set] }, $input;
}
```

This would create a data structure like this:

```
@country_sets  = (
                     (
                          USA,
                     ),
                     (
                          JPN,
                          CHN,
                     ),
                 )
```

No need for the complex `@results` since you're only going to have a single operation (GDP, etc.) for all involved.

However, I think I see what you want. We'll go with an array of arrays. Here's what I had before:

```
for my $hash_ref ( @array ) {
    if ( $hash_ref->{type} eq "subject" or $hash_ref->{type} eq "operator" ) {
        push @part_col, $hash_ref;
    }
}
```

We'll combine that and the code I offered right above which splits the countries into two sets:

```
my @country_sets;              # An array of arrays
my $set = 0                    # Which set you're on
for my $country_ref ( @array ) {
    next if $country_ref->{type} eq "variable";  # We don't want variables
    if ( $country_ref{type} eq "colon" ) {       # Switch to the other country set
        set += 1;
        next;
    }
    push @{ $country_sets[$set] }, $country_ref;
}
```

The first few entries will go into `$country_sets[0]` which will be an array reference. After the *colon* (which won't be input into the set), the second set of countries will go into `$country_sets[1]` which will be an other array_ref to a reference of hashes:

- `@country_sets` - Contains the input information into two sets
- `@country_sets[$x]` - A particular set of countries (and possibly operator)
- `@country_sets[$x]->[$y]` - A Particular country or operator
- `@country_sets[$x]->[$y]->{$key}` - A particular value from a particular country

Where `$x` goes from `0` to `1`. This will give you something like this:

```
$country_sets[0] = (
                       {
                          "type" => "subject",
                          "s" => "USA",
                           "subject" => "USA",
                           "variable" => "NGDP",
                       },
                   )

$country_sets[1] = (
                      {
                         "type" => "subject",
                         "s" => "JPN",
                         "subject" => "JPN",
                         "variable" => "NGDP",
                      },

                      { 
                          "type" => "operator",
                          "s" => "+",
                          "operator => "+",
                      },
                      {
                          "type" => "subject",
                          "s" => "CHN",
                          "subject" => "CHN",
                          "variable" => "NGDP",
                      },
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try that way and write my results. It is realy helpful. I updated my question with more information about data structure of @part_col_all. I hope that you understand what I'm trying to explain, if not I'll try it again.